Why do SSH config declarations stop executing when using SCP?
I am using OpenSSH config's "Match...exec" feature to conditionally connect to AWS EC2 instances via a tunnel. I have been building upon https://gist.github.com/Maks3w/de72b0160d5e6af958adc42eab014624; I have something like so:
Match host i-* exec "aws-proxy.sh %r %h ~/.ssh/aws-proxy.%h.%r"
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/aws-proxy.%h.%r
    ProxyCommand aws ec2-instance-connect open-tunnel --instance-id %h
    # Remove ephemeral key
    PermitLocalCommand yes
    LocalCommand rm ~/.ssh/aws-proxy.%h.%r*

This works well for ssh not for scp. In particular the last line is never called when using scp. I tried calling a script instead of calling rm directly, to make debugging easier, but the script never executes either.  It appears the declarations stop executing when using scp. To be clear, the first 2 directives work fine with scp, and therefore scp works, but the cleanup code is never called. Meanwhile everything works ok with ssh. Any ideas?

Tried verbose mode but there's no output to indicate why the declarations stop executing.
Tried calling a script instead of rm directly but script is never called either.
Started writing a wrapper script but realized writing a wrapper for scp is going to be a decent effort so thought I would ask for help first...

EDIT: I did end up writing a wrapper script for this. It's less flexible but does the job I need.

I think I found the real answer, or at least the most straightforward. man ssh_config says:

PermitLocalCommand
Allow local command execution via the LocalCommand option or using the !command escape sequence in ssh(1). The argument must be yes or no (the default).

I.e. LocalCommand only applies to ssh.

The corresponding manual page man scp doesn't list PermitLocalCommand nor LocalCommand as supported configuration options.
scp is a secure copy application designed in accordance to the Unix philosophy: it does one job and does it well. So, if you wan to have other actions besides copying, you have to write a "wrapper script" that can have any local commands there independently from the call to the scp, and even use conditions (e.g. to never remove the local file if copy was failed).

Thank you. It didn't even occur to me that different SSH commands would behave differently with respect to config declarations. That being said, despite "doing one job well" scp does support 60+ ssh config declarations, so I don't think that part of the answer adds any value, does it?

Different SSH commands don't  behave differently in the sense that they all put the same meaning into the same options. But they are, as you noticed, different, their purpose and behavior is different so is the set of options to control it. scp purpose is to copy files, not to run commands, so why should it react to LocalCommand at all? That would be strange if it did. OpenSSH is not Nero Burning ROM, it won't have options to to convert video files before uploading them via scp. if you want that, you have to write your own script. It's not that much of effort.
